# Receiving an out of memory exception with memorystream

Tags: c#, memory-management, kaltura

I'm attempting to write an application that will work with the open source media management platform, Kaltura.  Kaltura has provided some C# client libraries that talk to their web API and I have been able to talk to the server and upload videos successfully.  The problem I am having is that once files reach a certain size, I receive an out of memory exception and the program crashes.  I would like to attempt to fix this issue and submit the improved code back to the open source project, but being new to C#, I'm not exactly where to start.  Is there a better way than memorystream to do what they're doing?

Thanks in advance.

```
//Problematic code

private void PostMultiPartWithFiles(HttpWebRequest request, KalturaParams kparams, KalturaFiles kfiles)
    {
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        // use a memory stream because we don't know the content length of the request when we have multiple files
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();


        byte[] buffer;
        int bytesRead = 0;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in kparams)
        {
            sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + param.Key + "\"" + "\r\n");
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append(param.Value);
            sb.Append("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        }

        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FileStream> file in kfiles)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            FileStream fileStream = file.Value;
            sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + file.Key + "\"; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(fileStream.Name) + "\"" + "\r\n");
            sb.Append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + "\r\n");
            sb.Append("\r\n");

            // write the current string builder content
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // write the file content
            buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)fileStream.Length))];
            bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        request.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // write the memorty stream to the request stream
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)memStream.Length))];
        bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        requestStream.Close();
        memStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're loading the entire set of videos into your memory stream... That can (will) definitely cause your out of memory exception. You shouldn't be buffering it all into memory, instead just copying it straight to the `RequestStream`

Comment: Is this some kind of POST operation? The obvious issue would appear that the code does not use the request stream directly, but takes a detour down memory lane. This is bound to fail with big files. So, instead of writing to a Memorystream, write to the request stream and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version more or less how I would write it. It only compiles, but I haven't tested it. Note the use of a StreamWriter and the direct use of the request stream...

```
public class SendStuff
    {
        private readonly HttpWebRequest _request;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _kparams;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, FileStream> _kfiles;
        readonly string _boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

        public SendStuff(
            HttpWebRequest request, 
            Dictionary<string, string> kparams, 
            Dictionary<string, FileStream> kfiles)
        {
            _request = request;
            _kparams = kparams;
            _kfiles = kfiles;
            _request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + _boundary;
        }

        public void Do()
        {

            // Based on HTTP 1.1, if the server can determine the content length, it need not insist on
            // us sending one. If you are talking
            // to a "special" server, construct the headers beforehand, measure their length
            // and identify the file lengths of the files to be sent.

            using (var reqStream = _request.GetRequestStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(reqStream))
            {
                writer.NewLine = "\r\n";
                WriteBoundary(writer);
                WriteParams(writer);

                foreach (var file in _kfiles)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"", 
                        file.Key, 
                        Path.GetFileName(file.Value.Name));
                    writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                    writer.WriteLine();

                    WriteTheFileContent(reqStream, file.Value);

                    WriteBoundary(writer);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void WriteTheFileContent(Stream reqStream, Stream fileStream)
        {
            int bytesRead;
            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        private void WriteParams(StreamWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (var param in _kparams)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", param.Key);
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.WriteLine(param.Value);
                WriteBoundary(writer);
            }
        }

        private void WriteBoundary(TextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("\r\n--{0}\r\n", _boundary);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful.  I've been able to transfer the data although I think I have something wrong with how everything is being sent.  I should be able to eventually get it though.